# Improve list of lists?

Tags: java, list

I have a list of lists defined like this

```
List<List<String>> tblActuaciones = IntStream
        .rangeClosed(1, 6)
        .mapToObj(i
                -> getList(i)
                .stream()
                .map(HtmlElement::asText)
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
        )
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Then, to use the data in the list I use

```
for (int i = 0; i < tblActuaciones.get(0).size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < tblActuaciones.size(); j++) {
        ps.setString(j + 2, tblActuaciones.get(j).get(i));
    }
    ps.executeUpdate();
}
```

The question is: Is there a better (performance related) way to store and manipulate the data?

Note: I know all the lists returned by `getList(i)` have the same size

Comment: What is your performance problem? If you have not measured it, it's not a problem. "Premature optimization is the root of all evil."

Answer (score 0):

The current implementation executes a statement for each iteration of the external (`i`) loop. You could use batch executions to send them all in bulk to the database, which would probably slightly improve performance:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tblActuaciones.get(0).size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < tblActuaciones.size(); j++) {
        ps.setString(j + 2, tblActuaciones.get(j).get(i));
    }
    ps.addBatch();
}
ps.executeBatch();
```